# replacing element in a 2D List

Tags: python

consider this list

```
 my_data= [
     ['58', 'management', 'unknown', 'no'],
     ['44', 'technician', 'single', 'no'],
     ['33', 'entrepreneur', 'married', 'no'],
     ['47', 'blue-collar', 'married', 'no'],
     ['33', 'unknown', 'single', 'no'],
     ['35', 'management', 'unknown', 'no'],
     ['28', 'management', 'single', 'no'],
     ['42', 'entrepreneur', 'divorced', 'no'],
     ['58', 'retired', 'married', 'no'],
     ['43', 'technician', 'unknown', 'no']
]
```

I want to replace those unknown values with the most common element on the list 
and something is wrong with my code can anyone please correct it. 
it seems I need to call remove_unknown() twice to make it work

```
def most_common(lst):
    return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)

def remove_unknowns(ls):
    mycols=[]
    for cols in range(0, 4):
        for rows in xrange(len(ls)):
            if (type(ls[rows][cols]) is str):
                mycols.extend([ls[rows][cols]])
        #print mycols
        for rows in xrange(len(ls)):
            if (type(ls[rows][cols]) is str):
                if ls[rows][cols] == 'unknown':
                    ls[rows][cols]=most_common(mycols)
    return ls
remove_unknowns(my_data)
remove_unknowns(my_data)
```

my desired output is something like this:

```
my_data= [
 ['58', 'management', 'married', 'no'],
 ['44', 'technician', 'single', 'no'],
 ['33', 'entrepreneur', 'married', 'no'],
 ['47', 'blue-collar', 'married', 'no'],
 ['33', 'management', 'single', 'no'],
 ['35', 'management', 'married', 'no'],
 ['28', 'management', 'single', 'no'],
 ['42', 'entrepreneur', 'divorced', 'no'],
 ['58', 'retired', 'married', 'no'],
 ['43', 'technician', 'married', 'no']
```

]

Comment: It would be much easier to answer your question, if you provide desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by most common you mean in all the values combined first find the most common element and then iterate over the sublists replacing any Nones with the most common word:

```
my_data= [['58', 'management', 'unknown', 'no'],
 ['44', 'technician', 'single', 'no'],
 ['33', 'entrepreneur', 'married', 'no'],
 ['47', 'blue-collar', 'married', 'no'],
 ['33', 'unknown', 'single', 'no'],
 ['35', 'management', 'unknown', 'no'],
 ['28', 'management', 'single', 'no'],
 ['42', 'entrepreneur', 'divorced', 'no'],
 ['58', 'retired', 'married', 'no'],
 ['43', 'technician', 'unknown', 'no']]

from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

cn = Counter(chain(*my_data)).most_common(1)[0][0]
for sub in my_data:
    sub[:] = [cn if s == "unknown" else s for s in sub ]
```

If you actually want to get the max columns wise it is a bit more involved, you need to apply the same Counter logic but use one for each column:

```
from collections import Counter

# range over amount of columns and get the count for all words
l = [Counter() for _ in range(4)]
for sub in my_data:
    for ind, ele in enumerate(sub):
        l[ind][ele] += 1

# get most common word from each Counter
l[:] = [c.most_common(1)[0][0] for c in l]

for sub in my_data:
   # if word is unknown replace it using the appropriate column word
   sub[:] = [ l[ind] if ele == "unknown" else ele for ind, ele in enumerate(sub)]




from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(my_data)
```

Which will give you:

```
[['58', 'management', 'married', 'no'],
 ['44', 'technician', 'single', 'no'],
 ['33', 'entrepreneur', 'married', 'no'],
 ['47', 'blue-collar', 'married', 'no'],
 ['33', 'management', 'single', 'no'],
 ['35', 'management', 'married', 'no'],
 ['28', 'management', 'single', 'no'],
 ['42', 'entrepreneur', 'divorced', 'no'],
 ['58', 'retired', 'married', 'no'],
 ['43', 'technician', 'married', 'no']]
```

In the third column, either single or married are possible replacement values as they appear an equal amount of times.